# Multiple bindings from ReactiveUI search using ObservableAsPropertyHelper<>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a working implementation of a ReactiveUI asynchronous search routine within an WPF MVVM application based off of the following (legacy) example:

http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/05/reactivexaml-series-implementing-search-with-observableaspropertyhelper/

```
public class TheViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string query;

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<List<string>> matches;

    public TheViewModel()
    {
        var searchEngine = this.ObservableForProperty(input => input.Query)
                .Value()
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
                .Where(query => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) && query.Length > 1);

        var search = searchEngine.SelectMany(TheSearchService.DoSearchAsync);

        var latestResults =
            searchEngine.CombineLatest(search, (latestQuery, latestSearch) => latestSearch.Query != latestQuery ? null : latestSearch.Matches)
                .Where(result => result != null);

        matches = latestResults.ToProperty(this, result => result.Matches);
    }

    public string Query
    {
        get
        {
            return query;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref query, value);
        }
    }

    public List<string> Matches
    {
        get
        {
            return matches.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The ReactiveXAML is working as expected and I can easily bind to the Matches property like so

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="6" ItemsSource="{Binding Matches}" />
```

However I would like to refactor TheSearchService.DoSearchAsync() to return a more complex result structure sort of like this:

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public List<string> Matches { get; set; }
    public int MatchCount { get; set; }
    public double SearchTime { get; set; }
}
```

The matches would still be represented as a `List<string>` which would be bound to the same ListBox but I'd like also like to bind to a string metadata property on each search that returns the match count and search time in some sort of format such as:

```
 string.Format("Found {0} matches in {1}s", x.MatchCount, x.SearchTime)
```

How could I change the ViewModel implementation to allow multiple bindings for each search?

**Working implementation based on accepted answer**

```
public class TheViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    ...

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<SearchResult> results;

    public TheViewModel()
    {
        ...

        var latestResults = searchEngine.CombineLatest(search, (latestQuery, latestSearch) => latestSearch.Query != latestQuery ? null : latestSearch)
                .Where(result => result != null);

        results = latestResults.ToProperty(this, result => result.Result);
    }

    ...

    public SearchResult Result
    {
        get
        {
            return results.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the view**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Query, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Margin="6"
             FontSize="26" />
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="Found {0} matches in {1}s">
                <Binding Path="Result.MatchCount" />
                <Binding Path="Result.SearchTime" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
     Margin="6"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Result.Matches}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewmodel, instead of having instance of Matches create property of type `SearchResult` say MySearchResult. Also implement INotifyPropertyChanged on SearchResult. Update the SearchResult after every search operation

Now your listbox bindings will be like `<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="6" ItemsSource="{Binding MySearchResult.Matches}" />`

To show search result you can have textblock like below:

```
 <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Found {0} matches in {1}s">
            <Binding Path="MySearchResult.MatchCount"/>
             <Binding Path="MySearchResult.SearchTime"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you!  In keeping with the ReactiveUI flavor I used the ObservableAsPropertyHelper<SearchResult>.  My edit reflects the working solution.